# Trying to make NSString from scanf. Only getting the first word

Tags: objective-c

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
char inputBuffer[200];
NSString *input;
scanf("%s", inputBuffer);
input = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:inputBuffer];
NSLog(input);
```

Here's what happens:

```
bla bla bla
2010-11-08 23:17:03.670 TextGame[51147:a0f] bla
```

**inputBuffer** contains whole string. I tried to do `NSLog("%@", inputBuffer)` and there was whole string.

When I create this NSString it looks like it contains only the last word.

Please help me out with these I Googled like the whole internet and didn't get anywhere. :-)

Comment: Never use scanf in that way.  If you want to know why, just consider what happens to your buffer if somebody types in 201 non space characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf("%s", inputBuffer);` only reads a characters until a space is encountered. Therefore you get only "bla" stored in the buffer. You should use `gets(inputBuffer)`. This function "Reads characters from stdin and stores them as a string into str until a newline character ('\n') or the End-of-File is reached."

Comment: I just tried it in plain C at you're right. Whoa, I had no idea about this. So at least the problem is not in NSString. Thanks.

Comment: You should probably recommend using fgets(3) especially to people new to using ISO-C functions since gets is evil...

Comment: @Vojto: You should use fgets(inputBuffer, 200, stdin) instead of gets(inputBuffer)

Comment: Thanks that works nicely. Also, I had to remove \n from the end of the line.